# SN74LS93N is not counting as expected

Tags: integrated-circuit, counter, breadboard

I've got SN74LS93N chip that I am trying to get to work. 
I connected it as per datasheet but instead of counting, all outputs are flashing with clock signal...

[Video to circuit](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-OxZwZ7HkeO82rvSDuohI8MdHORKKfDm)

I read online and found advice to connected all unused pins to ground (not on this video) but the result is the same... Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks
pete

EDIT:

Posting how I connected the circuit. I used Falstad - Hope it's okay..

[Circuit](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+0.14549914146182014+29+5+43%0A!+default+0+1(CP1),2(MR1),3(MR2),5(Vcc),14(CP0)+8(Q2),9(Q1),10(Gnd),11(Q3),12(Q0)+SN74LS93N+%5C0%0A208+64+176+176+176+0+default+0+0+0+0+0%0AR+64+304+-16+304+1+2+100+2.5+2.5+0+0.5%0Av+-80+320+-80+272+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+-80+272+64+272+0%0Aw+160+240+192+240+0%0Aw+192+240+192+384+0%0Aw+192+384+16+384+0%0Aw+-80+384+-80+320+0%0Aw+64+208+16+208+0%0Aw+16+384+-80+384+0%0Aw+16+208+16+240+0%0Aw+16+240+16+384+0%0Aw+64+240+16+240+0%0Aw+160+176+256+176+0%0Aw+160+208+256+208+0%0Aw+160+272+256+272+0%0Aw+160+304+256+304+0%0Ar+256+176+336+176+0+220%0Ar+256+208+336+208+0+220%0Ar+256+272+336+272+0+220%0Ar+256+304+336+304+0+220%0A162+336+176+400+176+2+default-led+1+0+0+0.01%0A162+336+208+400+208+2+default-led+1+0+0+0.01%0A162+336+272+400+272+2+default-led+1+0+0+0.01%0A162+336+304+400+304+2+default-led+1+0+0+0.01%0Aw+400+176+400+208+0%0Aw+400+208+400+272+0%0Aw+400+272+400+304+0%0Aw+400+304+400+384+0%0Aw+400+384+192+384+0%0Aw+32+176+32+352+0%0Aw+32+352+160+352+0%0Aw+160+352+160+304+0%0Aw+32+176+64+176+0%0A)

[image: Circuit]

EDIT2:

I built the clock as per Ben Eater's instructions from YT.
Schematics below

[Clock Schematics](https://eater.net/schematics/clock.png)

Comment: You need to post a schematic circuit diagram of the actual circuit including signal sources and power supplies.

Comment: And tell us if this is a simulation or some actual hardware you've built and are testing.

Comment: this is actual circuit. I don't have a diagram but I can try to draw it somewhere...I use 5v power supply from USB port using USB-C cable that I cut and connected to breadboard

Comment: Where is your clock coming from? If a push-button, then you're probably getting a bunch of edges due to contact bounce, which will manifest as all outputs doing something. Buffer your button with an RC and schmidt trigger to give single edges for single pushes, or make a low speed oscillator so that it just sits there and counts slow enough to see what's happening

Comment: I don't see any resistor on the board. How have you connected the LEDs to the outputs?

Comment: As far as I know LS family don't need resistors on outputs as they have pull-down resistors built in. I user similar 4-bit counter before and it worked fine (CD4040) but this one acts strange...

Comment: One this that worries me is the "Logic" diagram from Datasheet... [Screen Shot](https://imgur.com/2z74wc3)... I can't see to make this work. I tried circuit lab and it actually behaves as my circuit unless I am doing something wrong...

Comment: @aberforth There is an inbuilt schematic editor which is very intuitive to use and gives quite good results. In question or answer editing use Ctrl-M or cct symbol near top centre || The resistors referred to by others are in series with the LEDs. Assuming a device is OK  for use without resistors because the outputs are current limited will often lead to bad results.

Answer (score 15):

I see two issues:

1. No decoupling caps. Edit: Add decoupling caps (see comment). When ICs switch state they draw a pulse of current on the 5V. Your power wires have enough inductance to cause the 5V to momentarily dip to near zero. This causes the IC to lose it memory.
2. No series resistors on your LEDs, although some LEDs have built-in resistors, so I can't be sure.

For more information, you need to draw a schematic, I can't see all the connections.

Comment: I added the 220Ohms resitors for each LED and they all flash at the same time on with the clock signal...

Comment: @aberforth ADD A SCHEMATIC

Comment: This answer which comes before the user has even posted a schematic may be an attempt at wry humor but it is not that funny. Down voting because the information provided may be entirely wrong.

Comment: @aberforth - Put an electrolytic cap (>=22 uF) from 5V to ground anywhere on your breadboard. Put a ceramic cap (0.1 uF) directly from pin 5 to pin 10 on the IC. It needs to be a close to the IC as possible.

Comment: @Mattman944 - I can't see how can this resolve my issue? My issue is that 4 bits reacts to the clock signal at the same time, I can try that but I am not sure if i got those caps on hand...

Comment: @Mattman944 - It worked! I hooked up 1uF cap between VCC and ground and it's counting now... I am not sure what the bypass CAP is doing exactly so I think I need to read up on that... Thanks. If you want to write an answer please do so so I can mark it as answered.

Comment: @aberforth - adding decoupling caps was in my answer.

Comment: @MichaelKaras - I looked at the video, saw two potential issues. I made an educated guess, I was right.

Comment: @MichaelKaras a little grumpy during the lockdown or something?

Comment: I feel dumb now... decoupling caps were my issue too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From your diagram, you don't appear to have it correctly connected: you appear to have `QC` (8) connected to `CKA` (14) and feeding `CKB` (1).  Datasheet says you should have `CKB` (1) connected to `QA` (12) and feed `CKA` (14).

[image]
From [TI Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls90.pdf)

Comment: Sorry, I drew it incorrectly, corrected now